# IIS Windows 2016 ecdsa signed certificate

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2016, iis-10

Does anyone know if IIS supports certificates signed with sha256ecdsa?

If viewed with openssl, i have the following parameters:
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
Public Key Info: NIST CURVE: P-384

The problem is with this certificate I can't get a successful TLS handshake.
I wonder if the problem is the signature algorithm or the ECDSA curve (both the certificate and the CA use P-384 public keys).

Comment: IIS in Windows supports ECC keys for 11 years (since Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 RTM). There are no algorithm support problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that P384 cipher suits are not enabled by default it seems.

I solved it using GPO with a set "Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->Network/SSL Configuration Settings->SSL Cipher Suite Order"

I added ciphers such as "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384".

After this it could use the certificate as expected.